# Newton - Raphson inversion algorithm in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I am trying to implement Newton - Raphson inversion algotihm in assembly according to this equation:

```
Xn+1 = Xn(2-b*Xn)
```

My function is:

```
.data
const:
    .int 2
.text
.global inversion
inversion:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    fldl    8(%ebp)         # load b
    fldl    12(%ebp)        # load X0
inv:    
    fst     %st(2)          # save Xn
    fmul    %st(1), %st(0)      # b*Xn
    fsubr   const           # 2-b*Xn
    fmul    %st(2), %st(0)      # Xn(2-b*Xn)
    fcomi   %st(2), %st(0)      # check if it the same result as before
jne inv                 # jump
                    # it should return the st(0)
leave
ret
```

And my C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern float inversion (float a, float b);

int main(void)
{
    float x = inversion (5,0.1);
    printf ("%f\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that this function doesn't return anything, and when I am debuggin it with gdb it shows that my function never stops, because values are never the same. In my opinion it's load bad numbers, it's what I am reading after loading data on stack (st(0), st(1), st(2)):

```
st0            2.6342588374767957140994886365053441e-314    (raw 0x3bed9ee6666680000000)
st1            5.2386907379892329317261356891322066e-11 (raw 0x3fdce6666a0500000000)
st2            2.6342588374767957140994886365053441e-314    (raw 0x3bed9ee6666680000000)
```

Thanks for all your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `gdb` pointed you in the right direction: you are loading the arguments wrong. You used `fldl` where the `l` means `double` when dealing with floating point instructions. I guess you thought the `l` meant `4 bytes`. To load 4 byte floats you need the `flds` instruction.

Furthermore, `fsubr` expects a floating point number but you give it an integer. Solution: change `.int 2` to `.float 2`. Also change to `fsubrs` for safety (although that is the default).

Finally, you are leaving 3 values on the fpu stack, which is not according to the expected calling convention and can cause problems later. You should only leave the return value there.

Comment: Thanks you so much, it was so helpful.

Comment: Could you tell me what if I would like to use double?

Comment: As I said, the `l` suffix is for doubles. Note that the fpu normally  calculates to 80 bits precision, the conversion only happens during load and store.

Comment: I've got one more problem. When I'm using float it calculates properly for bigger numbers, for example: inversion (750,0.001); it returns 0.001333, so it's good answer, but when I'm changing to double it returns -inf. I realized that it returns -inf when the second argument is lower than 0.3. It's wired and I have to solve it because I need to calculates it for so much bigger numbers. My code is: http://pastebin.com/GCpsLZuk

Comment: "fpu calculates to 80 bits precision" - this depends on how fcw is set, which could be set by the C start up code that calls main. To set for 80 bit: | fcw dw 0 | ... | fnstcw fcw | or fcw,0300h | fldcw fcw | .